# CodeIgniter Active Record: prevent duplicate on insert

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying out CodeIgniter with a simple users table in SQLLite, which comprises of id, name, email.

How can I prevent duplicates from being inserted when using Active Record?

I've tried the following, but it just keep creating duplicates...

```
$data = array(
  'email' => 'd@d.com' ,
  'name' => 'dave' 
);

$this->db->where('users.email != ', 'd@d.com');
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add UNIQUE INDEX as mentioned for complete safety.

Then you could... do something like this:

```
$email = 'd@d.com';
$name = 'dave';

$this->db->query("
INSERT INTO users VALUES (email, name)
SELECT email, name
FROM (SELECT ? AS email, ? AS name) AS h
HAVING ! (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email = h.email)
", array($email, $name));
```

Comment: No joy. Just get the following: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\htdocs\CodeIgniter\system\database\drivers\pdo\pdo_driver.php on line 193

Comment: Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I realized first now that you didn't use MySQL. Therefor this query might not work fully, sorry. You could try reform above to use `INSERT IGNORE ...` and `VALUES (...)` instead of `SELECT` after adding INDEX.